# Implementing Firefox Extension vs Implementing Chome Plugin

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension

I have worked on a chrome plugin for one of the cloud based product. For The Chrome we have used third partly JS libraries like BackboneJS etc. Now I have to design a Firefox Extension, I am trying to figure out how much code we can reuse. Apparently spending few hours with Mozilla Developer site it seems like for Firefox Extension we have to use XUL for the UI. Not sure if we can use the html and javascript functions from Chrome App for the Firefox Extension, or what would be the approach to estimate the effort. My Understanding is that we have to do it from the scratch since like Chrome in FF we dont have concepts like background page etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherent that prevents you from implementing a UI in HTML/JS. You might have to wrap it in an XUL [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/iframe), or [`<browser>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/browser) (potentially other elements) within a [`<window>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/window) (Firefox will open pure HTML).

The key issue regarding extensions is that they execute in an elevated security context vs. webpages.  As such, they have the ability to affect a much larger range of things in the browser and on the users system. When [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/iframe), or [`<browser>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/browser) elements are used, they have a property `type` which defaults to having the contents operating in the elevated security context.  The default value is `type="chrome"` which makes the content opened be in the extension's higher security context.

Additional docs from MDN regarding security concerns with opening content in [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/iframe), or [`<browser>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/browser) elements which is not sourced from your extension distribution:  [Security best practices in extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Security_best_practices_in_extensions) and [Displaying web content in an extension without security issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Displaying_web_content_in_an_extension_without_security_issues)

As to your JavaScript: You should be able to re-use a significant amount of it. At a minimum, the logic.  Obviously, there will be more significant differences in how you accomplish interfacing to the aspects of the browsers which are not covered under standards documents (e.g. DOM manipulation should be very close, just as it is for webpage JS).

Comment: To be more specific, When I compare the architecture of Chrome Extension with Firefox Extension, I did not found background page in Chrome equivalent in Firefox.

Comment: There are a wide variety of methods which could be used to accomplish having a script that is always running. How to do so depends on multiple considerations.  At a minimum, what [type of add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) you are doing ([Overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions), [Bootstrapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), or [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK)) and what you want the code to be doing.

Comment: I am following the Add-on SDK steps to build the extension.